# Creating an interface for a protobuf-net assembly

Tags: protobuf-net

I created an assembly that contains a proto-file and the generated pb.cs-file.

I want to access these classes from other assemblies, but since protogen generates all classes as "internal", I can't.
What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protogen does *not* normally generate `internal` classes; it actually uses:

```
public partial class <xsl:call-template name="pascal"/>
```

(where `pascal` is a template that emits the type name, appropriately cased).

In fact, the only mention of `internal` is in `$keywords`, which it uses to decide whether to use `Foo` versus `@Foo`.

If it is emitting `internal`, then that means somebody in your team has customised `csharp.xslt` to provide custom code generation. So... don't do that ;p

Comment: Yep, you are super right. I took a mint csharp.xslt and it produces public partial classes. Thank you!